# In which direction does the pseudo force act?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

[image]

The point O is where the small mass is attached. I'm trying to find out the minimum velocity that should be given to the mass so that it can complete a full circle but if the fixed point is accelerating, how will it affect the answer? What force will act on the particle?

Comment: Can't you just apply the equivalence principle?

Comment: Uh what is that? I haven't really covered relativity so I don't know how to...

Comment: Just consider that the acceleration $a$ becomes a pseudo force field in the opposite direction and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

So I took a special case when a=g/3 and there's a downward pseudo force and got this answer. Can someone confirm this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo force acts in the vertically downward direction if the acceleration is vertically up.
If the acceleration is given in vector form as *xi+yj* then the pseudo force is  m(*-xi-yj*). Where m is the mass of body.

To find minimum velocity, we must assume that the tension in the string is 0 at the highest point, hence only the force due to gravity and force due to pseudo force would contribute to the net centripetal force ($\frac{mv^2}{r}$). Where *v* is the velocity at the highest point . In this way the acceleration affects the minimum velocity.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and confirm whether it's the right way.

Comment: Also in that case if the point accelerates only in the x-direction, will it have no effect on the value of the minimum velocity required to complete the circle because at the topmost point the pseudo force won't be acting along the y-axis?